# How can order by FIELD in Symfony2 with doctrine

Tags: symfony, doctrine

Hello I worked with Symfony2 and Doctrine.

I want to order by my custom order with doctrine

```
SELECT id_product, pro_name FROM product ORDER BY FIELD(id_product,3,5,2)
```

I have tried

```
    $rang_1=array(3,5,2);
    $products = $em->getRepository('CompanyMyBundle:Product')->findBy(array('public' => 1,'idProduct'=>$rang_1), array('idProduct'=>$rang_1), 5);
```

AND

```
$sql = $em->createQuery("SELECT p FROM CompanyMyBundle:Product p WHERE l.public = 1 AND l.idProduct IN (".implode(',',$rang_1).")  ORDER BY FIELD(l.idProduct,".implode(',',$rang_1).")")->setMaxResults(5);
```

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have any experience with the ORDER BY FIELD-expression, but have you seen [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5957330/doctrine-2-mysql-field-function-in-order-by) already? Maybe it can help you out?

Seems like they've written a Doctrine 2 extension that handles the implementation for FIELD...