# orderBy several Columns - Doctrine QueryBuilder

Tags: sql, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I want to use orderBY on several Columns, but they should act like one single column.
The table looks something like that:

```
col1 | col2
5    |
2    |
     | 3
7    |
     | 1
     | 1
```

The result should look like that:

```
col1 | col2
     | 1
     | 1
2    |
     | 3
5    |
7    |
```

If we would be using raw SQL there would be Methods, like using `COALESCE`.

But how could this be achieved in the Doctrine QueryBuilder?

### Edit:

I tried the orderBy like this:

```
qb->orderBy("COALESCE(col1, col2)", "DESC");
```

And like this

```
qb->add("orderBy", "COALESCE(col1, col2) DESC");
```

But both times I was thrown the following Error:

```
[Syntax Error] line 0, col 700: Error: Expected end of string, got '('
```

Comment: As the good solution - create custom doctrine function for implement method COALESCE.

Comment: Have you tried coalesce? It is included in language grammar

Comment: @Lolo Thank you for your comment. I edited my Question above. Maybe I used it the wrong way?

Comment: @ZhukV Sorry, but I am probably not fit enough with Doctrine to do so. Do you have any further documentation/information on that?

Comment: Seems to be impossible: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18148818/using-is-null-and-coalesce-in-orderby-doctrine-querybuilder

Comment: @StephanVierkant Thanks, I saw this post before, but they just found no solution. I thought maybe we can find something else. I am also not bound to coalesce, this just would have been my solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to add order column in select statement and then order by it.

```
$qb = $em->createQueryBuilder();
$qb
    ->select('entity', 'COALESCE(col1, col2) as orderCol')
    ->from('Namespace/Entity', 'entity')
    ->orderBy('orderCol', 'DESC')
```

---

Maybe it can be helpful to use [IF](https://github.com/beberlei/DoctrineExtensions/blob/master/lib/DoctrineExtensions/Query/Mysql/IfElse.php) from [beberlei/DoctrineExtensions](https://github.com/beberlei/DoctrineExtensions) library. Install it with composer(or you can just copy one file if you want) and

register function in *config.yml*

```
doctrine:
    orm:
      entity_managers:
        default:
          dql:
            string_functions:
              IF: DoctrineExtensions\Query\Mysql\IfElse
```

and build a query

```
$qb = $em->createQueryBuilder();
$qb
    ->select('entity', 'IF(col1, col1, col2) as orderCol')
    ->from('Namespace/Entity', 'entity')
    ->orderBy('orderCol', 'DESC')
```

---

Another option is to use [Native Query](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/native-sql.html) with pure mysql and map result to entities.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I will test this tomorrow and will give you feedback on this. But I really don't want to use raw mysql queries. Do you know what would be more efficient. The IF or the COALESCE?

Comment: I can confirm that @forgottenbas's solution will work as I had similar situation few days ago. As addition I would also include `HIDDEN` keyword to preserve clean resultset structure, but that is by no means mandatory: `COALESCE(col1, col2) as HIDDEN orderCol`

Comment: @Robin dont know which is faster, usually its not the slowest part of a query, but where are some information in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4747877/mysql-ifnull-vs-coalesce-which-is-faster)

Comment: @Jovan Perovic: Thanks for **HIDDEN!** This is mandatory if you use it as the 'query_builder' argument for an EntityType field in Symfony 2.8!