# doctrine2 order by array with ids

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine-odm, doctrine-query

How I can with doctrine2 order by array with ids ?

I have this query:

```
$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('u')
        ->select('u', 'n', 'c')
        ->leftJoin('u.notifications', 'n')
        ->leftJoin('u.channel', 'c')
        ->andWhere('u.id IN (:ids)')
        ->setParameter('ids', $ids);
```

I want that the result has the same order that array with ids, is possible do it ?

Thanks

**SOLUTION:**

Use FIELD mysql extension with https://github.com/beberlei/DoctrineExtensions

:)

Thanks

Comment: Questions should never contain solutions -- that is what answers are for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, it is possible using FIELD mysql extension with https://github.com/beberlei/DoctrineExtensions

Thanks

Marc

Comment: Here is an example of how to register this DQL function in Symfony and how to use it, just in case that you are using MySQL as well: https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/1162/how-to-order-a-doctrine-2-query-result-by-a-specific-order-of-an-array-using-mysql-in-symfony-5

Answer (score 7):

Simple solution that doesn't require presorting query result:

```
 $idPositions = array_flip($userIds); // Mapping of id to position
 usort($users, function($userA, $userB) use ($idPositions) {
     return $idPositions[$userA->id] - $idPositions[$userB->id];
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using MySQL, [sorting with the FIELD()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/396748/ordering-by-the-order-of-values-in-a-sql-in-clause/396771#396771) function could accomplish this. DQL doesn't have built-in support for this function, so you'll either have to [create a user defined function](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/cookbook/dql-user-defined-functions.html) (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5957330/doctrine-2-mysql-field-function-in-order-by)), or create a native query.

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution that is probably very inefficient, but it works. Make sure your results are ordered by `id`.

```
$users = $entityManager
    ->getRepository('User')
    ->findById($userIds, ['id' => 'ASC']);

$userIdsCopy = $userIds;
sort($userIdsCopy);
array_multisort($userIds, $userIdsCopy);
array_multisort($userIdsCopy, $users);
```

It's hard to explain how this works, but basically you "remember" the operations that happen when you sort the userId-array, then you apply the opposite of that to the query result.

Answer (score -1):

Which id do you want to order by?

You can use...

```
->orderBy('u.id', 'asc')
// or n.id
// or c.id
```

Or you can use multiple order by's ("by's" doesn't seem right to me)...

```
->addOrderBy('u.id', 'asc')
->addOrderBy('u.name', 'desc') // if it exists
```