# Order by FIELD() using doctrine, is it possible?

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine, dql

I am working on a project which is built using Symfony and Doctrine, however I am still new to the whole setup.

Cut a long story short I have need to order a result set by the order of the array used in the select.

Which I believe could be done using the FIELD() function, however from my investigations it doesn't look like its possible using Doctrine.

For example, I am stumped as how I can utilise FIELD() in a query like below (if its even possible):

```
return $this
            ->createQueryBuilder('a')
            ->where('a.identifier IN (:identifiers)')
            ->setParameter('identifiers',$identifiers)
            ->getQuery()
            ->getResult();
```

Comment: Seems you could use DoctrineExtensions to [register FIELD() as a custom method](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10164133/1078488). Do note that using extensions may break compatibility for other RDBS types.

Comment: [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377).

Comment: I am happy to accept any solution, this was just my initial thoughts.

Comment: Can't propose another solution, since I've no idea what problem you're trying to solve.  In particular, whence do you obtain the desired ordering?

Comment: The original desired ordering comes from a query to a third party which returns a list of identifiers in an array. The order of the array is the order which I need to pull the data by identifier from the local database.

Comment: JimL solution worked a treat, if he adds it as an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 4):

I am using doctrine version 1.2.4 and using following query to order by specific values.

```
$query->orderBy('FIELD(str,str1,str2,str3,...)');
```

Comment: `Expected known function, got 'FIELD'` with `doctrine/orm` v2.5.14.

Comment: `$queryBuilder->orderBy('FIELD(my_alias.id,1,2,3)');` in Doctrine 2.6 works just fine

Comment: @pmishev I [don't think so](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#dql-functions). Not without [beberlei/DoctrineExtensions](https://github.com/beberlei/DoctrineExtensions).

Answer (score 0):

I'm using doctrine v2.5.x. It does not support the FIELD function.

I found and used this file.
https://github.com/beberlei/DoctrineExtensions/blob/master/src/Query/Mysql/Field.php

Or you can install the extension.