# Symfony2 QueryBuilder return product query in order of ids

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, query-builder

I have a list of ids in any order:

```
array(57, 12, 29, 25, 11)
```

With Symfony`s QueryBuilder I need to return only these products form all the database objects, and they should be returned in this specific order.

I need to return the **Query**, not result.

I am trying all different approaches:

```
    public function querySortedProductsInCategories($id, $type, $slug, $sort)
    {

        $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('p');
        $qb->addSelect(array('p', 'gallery'));
        $qb->addSelect(array('p', 'media'));
        $qb->addSelect(array('p', 'image'));
        $qb->leftJoin("p." . $type, "c");
        $qb->leftJoin('p.gallery', 'gallery');
        $qb->leftJoin('gallery.galleryHasMedias', 'media');
        $qb->leftJoin('media.media', 'image');
        $qb->where("c." . $type. "= :id ");
        $qb->andWhere("p.status = 1 ");
        $qb->SetParameter('id', $id);
//        $qb->andWhere($qb->expr()->in('p.id', $sort));
//        $qb->andWhere("p.id IN (:sort) ");
//        $qb->SetParameter('sort', $sort);
        return $qb->getQuery();
    }
```

I tried the `IN` statement.... it returns the list I need, but not in the correct order.

Now I am starting to think that it is not even possible to do that. Stackoverflow is my last chance of figuring out this...

UPDATE:

Tried to create my DQL Function, but I get errors. First time doing this and I have no idea whats going on...

```
class Field extends \Doctrine\ORM\Query\AST\Functions\FunctionNode
{

    /**
     * @override
     */
    public function parse(\Doctrine\ORM\Query\Parser $parser) {
        $parser->match(Lexer::T_IDENTIFIER);
        $parser->match(Lexer::T_OPEN_PARENTHESIS);
        $this->stringPrimary = $parser->StringPrimary();
        $parser->match(Lexer::T_COMMA);
        $this->stringSecondary = $parser->StringPrimary();
        $parser->match(Lexer::T_COMMA);
        $this->stringThird = $parser->StringPrimary();
        $parser->match(Lexer::T_CLOSE_PARENTHESIS);
    }


    /**
     * @param \Doctrine\ORM\Query\SqlWalker $sqlWalker
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getSql(\Doctrine\ORM\Query\SqlWalker $sqlWalker)
    {
        // TODO: Implement getSql() method.
    }

}
```

The QUERY:

```
        $em = $this->getEntityManager();
        $doctrineConfig = $em->getConfiguration();
        $doctrineConfig->addCustomStringFunction('FIELD', 'Mp\ShopBundle\Doctrine\Field');

        $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('p');
        $qb->addSelect(array('p', 'gallery'));
        $qb->addSelect(array('p', 'media'));
        $qb->addSelect(array('p', 'image'));
        $qb->addSelect(array("p, field(p.id, " . implode(", ", $sort) . ") as HIDDEN field"));
        $qb->leftJoin("p." . $type, "c");
        $qb->leftJoin('p.gallery', 'gallery');
        $qb->leftJoin('gallery.galleryHasMedias', 'media');
        $qb->leftJoin('media.media', 'image');
//        $qb->where("p.id = :sort ");
        $qb->where("c." . $type. "= :id ");
        $qb->andWhere($qb->expr()->in('p.id', $sort));
        $qb->andWhere("p.status = 1 ");
        $qb->setParameter('id', $id);
//        $qb->setParameter('sort', $sort);
        $qb->orderBy('field');
        return $qb->getQuery();
```

ERROR:

```
Error: Expected StateFieldPathExpression | string | InputParameter | FunctionsReturningStrings | AggregateExpression, got '23'
```

QUERY:

```
[1/2] QueryException: SELECT p, p, gallery, p, media, p, image, p, field(p.id, 23, 40, 30, 24, 42, 37, 38, 58, 33, 8, 34, 35, 36, 28, 51, 14, 1) as HIDDEN field FROM Mp\ShopBundle\Entity\Product p LEFT JOIN p.subcategory c LEFT JOIN p.gallery gallery LEFT JOIN gallery.galleryHasMedias media LEFT JOIN media.media image WHERE c.subcategory= :id AND p.id IN(23, 40, 30, 24, 42, 37, 38, 58, 33, 8, 34, 35, 36, 28, 51, 14, 1) AND p.status = 1 ORDER BY field ASC
```

Comment: What do you get as a return value when you call this method?

Comment: I get the list of products, but they are ordered simply from first to last.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With MySQL, you can create a DQL function to be able to use [FIELD](http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/string-functions/mysql-field-function.php) :

See this other similar question :

[Doctrine 2 mysql FIELD function in order by](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5957330/doctrine-2-mysql-field-function-in-order-by)

Comment: Thanks, looks like I need to install the DoctrineExtension bundle in symfony.. Do you know witch is the right bundle?

Comment: Not a bundle. You have to write your own DQL 'FIELD' function. Docs http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/custom_dql_functions.html and http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/cookbook/dql-user-defined-functions.html

Comment: This bundle already implements this function (and much more): https://github.com/wiredmedia/doctrine-extensions but it's pretty old. I don't know, if it still works with newest version of Doctrine.

Comment: Here's something that looks interesting: https://github.com/beberlei/DoctrineExtensions

Comment: I would suggest to simply copy beberlei's solution. Just take `Field` class if you don't what to install whole library. https://github.com/beberlei/DoctrineExtensions/blob/master/src/Query/Mysql/Field.php

Answer (score 0):

You can make an order by case:

```
$customOrderString = $this->generateCase($ids);
if(!empty($customOrderString)) {
    $db->addSelect("(CASE {$customOrderString} ELSE 3 END) AS HIDDEN ORD ");
    $db->orderBy('ORD', 'DESC');
}
return $qb->getQuery();

 .....
private generateCase($ids) {
    $caseString = '';
    foreach($ids as $index=>$id) {
        $caseString .= "WHEN $id THEN $index";
    }
    return $caseString;
}
```

Comment: well ofcourse it does... But thats not what I need. orderBy can only order asc or desc.. I need to order by my array(57, 12, 29, 25, 11)

Comment: The commented part://        $qb->andWhere("p.id IN (:sort) ");
//        $qb->SetParameter('sort', $sort);

Comment: $sort is the array

Comment: 10 mins I'll post the answer

Comment: Although you can make an associative array based on those keys rather than the sort